# How to speed up finding duplicates in a dataframe column

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I wish to find the indexes where sequences of duplicate values occur in a dataframe column.  I want the results to be a list of lists where each sublist is an individual sequence of duplicate value indexes.

My current code works but is quite slow (apx 15 msec for 10% duplicates in a 10,000 row dataframe):

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import time

# Given a dataframe and column, return a list of lists where each sublist
# contains indexes of the sequential duplicates
def duplicate_ranges(df, c):
    return to_ranges(df[c].shift(1) == df[c])

# Take a pandas Series of booleans and return a list of lists where each 
# sub-list is the indexs of sequential true values in the list
def to_ranges(s):
    r = []
    g = []
    for k, v in s.items():
        if v == True:
            g.append(k)
        elif len(g) > 0:
            r.append(g)
            g = []
    if len(g) > 0:
        r.append(g)
    return r

def bench_it(n):
    data = {"A": np.random.randint(10, 10000)}
    idxs = pd.date_range(start='2000-01-01', periods=10000)
    df = pd.DataFrame(data, index=idxs)
    t = time.time()
    for _ in range(0, n):
        r = duplicate_ranges(df, 'A')
    t = time.time() - t
    print("{:d} iterations took {:.1f} msec".format(n, 1000*t))

bench_it(1000)
```

From what I can tell, all the time is spent in the main loop of to_ranges().  I'm rather new to pandas and numpy, could anyone suggest a way to speed this up?

Comment: Your code sample here seems to be bugged - `df` is going to have one, identical value in column `'A'`

Comment: np.random.randint(10, 10000) generates a list of 10000 random integers in the range 0 to 9

Comment: Weirdly, if I change the line:  if v == True:  to be just:  if v:, it speeds up to about 8 ms.

Comment: np.random.randint(10, 10000) doesn't have a size specified. Might be version specific? np.random.randint(10, size=10000) works

Answer (score 2):

Here's a fast method that takes advantage of efficient operations within `scipy.sparse`:

```
from scipy.sparse import csr_matrix

def duplicate_ranges(df, c):
    index, values = df.index.values, df[c].values

    data = values
    indices = np.arange(len(values))
    indptr = np.concatenate([[0], np.where(np.diff(values) != 0)[0] + 1,
                             [len(values)]])

    M = csr_matrix((index, indices, indptr))[np.diff(indptr) > 1]
    M.sort_indices()
    return np.split(M.data, M.indptr[1:-1])
```

It's about an order of magnitude faster than other methods here, because it avoids Python loops over the full array (though there are some Python loops within the `split()` function, called only across a subset of the array).

---

*old answer:*

Here's a fast way to solve this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1, 2, 3, 3, 3, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2]})

def duplicate_ranges(df, c):
    index, values = df.index.values, df[c].values
    ranges = np.split(index, np.where(np.diff(values) != 0)[0] + 1)
    return [list(r) for r in ranges if len(r) > 1]

duplicate_ranges(df, 'A')
# [[2, 3, 4], [6, 7], [8, 9]]
```

Since it avoids nested loops and requires only a single pass through the full column, it should be much faster than other approaches.

Comment: I was very hopeful that this would be much faster, but oddly it's about the same speed as my revised version.  It also includes the first index of each duplicate sequence while my example doesn't.  But that's not a big deal, I can work around it.

Comment: I thought that leaving the first index out was a bug, to be honest :)

Comment: You can change the last line to ``[list(r[1:]) for r in ranges if len(r) > 1]`` if you want it to match your results. I think the poor speed comes from the list comprehension... there may be a way around that...

Comment: I added an approach that uses ``scipy.sparse`` to avoid the overhead of looping/chunking the array.